# Multilevel panels : outer panel disabled and inner panel enabled

Tags: .net

I have multi level panels. Where I need to set the outer panel as enabled false and inner panel as enabled true. How can I do so?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you can't.

Best solution I can offer is that you disable all the other controls on your outer panel except for the inner panel. That will give the same impression as the outer panel being disabled.